# Trying to create Shiny time-series graph of gapminder using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am new to Shiny and, as an exercise, I am trying to assess global trends over time using the Gapminder data set. My aim is to produce a basic app that allows me to plot life expectancy (lifeExp), population (pop) and  GDP per capita (gdpPercap) over time (year) separately. However, when I enter the following code all I get is a ggplot with a straight line. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

```
library(shiny)
library(gapminder)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(

    selectInput(inputId = "variables",
                label = "Select Variable",
                choices = names(gapminder[, 4:6])),
    plotOutput("plot")

)

server <- function(input, output){

output$plot <- renderPlot({

        data <- gapminder %>% group_by(year) %>%
                              summarise(lifeExp = mean(lifeExp, na.rm = T),
                                        pop = mean(pop, na.rm = T),
                                        gdpPercap = mean(gdpPercap, na.rm = T))

        ggplot(data, aes(x = year, y = input$variables)) + geom_line()

    })    

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With modern versions of `ggplot2` `rlang`, we may modify the `aes` call to `aes(x = year, y = .data[[input$variables]]))` and do:

```
library(shiny)
library(gapminder)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(

  selectInput(inputId = "variables",
              label = "Select Variable",
              choices = names(gapminder[, 4:6])),
  plotOutput("plot")

)

server <- function(input, output){

  output$plot <- renderPlot({

    data <- gapminder %>% group_by(year) %>%
      summarise(lifeExp = mean(lifeExp, na.rm = TRUE),
                pop = mean(pop, na.rm = TRUE),
                gdpPercap = mean(gdpPercap, na.rm = TRUE))

    ggplot(data, aes(x = year, y = .data[[input$variables]])) + 
      geom_line()

  })    

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Reference: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/dev/articles/ggplot2-in-packages.html#using-aes-and-vars-in-a-package-function